# MSVC: "too few arguments in function call" when omitting optional parameter

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, optional-parameters

in a WDF driver project I'm writing in Visual Studio 2013, I've got this function:

```
ZwWaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, 0);
```

which gives the "too few arguments in function call" error, if I omit the last parameter, which is optional:

```
    NTSTATUS ZwWaitForSingleObject(
  _In_     HANDLE         Handle,
  _In_     BOOLEAN        Alertable,
  _In_opt_ PLARGE_INTEGER Timeout
);
```

The problem is, I ***have to*** omit it, I cannot just set it to NULL. Because, as MSDN says:

> If a Timeout parameter is not specified, then the wait will not be
>    satisfied until the object attains a state of Signaled.  If an explicit Timeout value of zero is specified, then no
>    wait will occur if the wait cannot be satisfied immediately.

So, the question is: have you got any idea on why Visual C++ forces me to type in the optional parameter on a system function call?
How can it be avoided?

Comment: Is the extension of your file `.c`?

Comment: It's not "optional" as in C++ default argument. It is a pointer, so you should be passing NULL.

Comment: @MohitJain Yes. But I also tried to set it to .cpp, and I also set the "Compile as C++ Code (/TP)" option, but doesn't solve.

Comment: C does not have "optional" parameters. Tag changed to C++

Comment: @Banex, the problem is, if I set the Timeout parameter to zero, as MSDN says, the behaviour of ZwWaitForSingleObject will be different then NOT specyfing it

Comment: Did you try passing third parameter as NULL? `ZwWaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, 0, 0);`

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Banex, WIN32 types which have a prefix `P` means they are pointer types, `PLARGE_INTEGER` is a *pointer* to `LARGE_INTEGER`. Since the functions have to be callable from C as well as C++, they can't have arguments with default values (which is a C++ specific feature), and so pointers are used, and to the "optional" part is that the pointer have to be `NULL` if the argument is not to be used. Also, in C++, `0` *is* the null pointer (a.k.a. `NULL`). So passing `0` as the third argument is the same as passing `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's optional as in: you don't have to pass a valid value if you don't want to but you *have* to pass something, the optional parameters don't work the same as a default argument in C++ (even though this question is already tagged as `C`).

The variable type of `Timeout` is `PLARGE_INTEGER` which is a pointer to a LARGE_INTEGER. Creating a LARGE_INTEGER and setting it's values to 0 and passing the created LARGE_INTEGER will cause the behaviour you specified :

> If an explicit Timeout value of zero is specified, then no wait will
>   occur if the wait cannot be satisfied immediately.

However, this won't happen when you simply pass `NULL` as argument, it's the same as `a Timeout parameter is not specified`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, now I understand.

Answer (score 4):

`zero` is not the same as `NULL`. This is a `C` API, there are no "optional" parameters. So passing `NULL` means *not specified* The two cases in your quoted documentation are

```
ZwWaitForSingleObject(handle, 0, NULL);
/* or ZwWaitForSingleObject(handle, 0, 0); which is the same */
```

vs

```
LARGE_INTEGER timeout;
timeout.QuadPart = 0L;
ZwWaitForSingleObject(handle, 0, &timeout);
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, now I understand.
I didn't think about the difference between passing a valid pointer to a null value, and passing a null pointer.